# Brain.js example

Tags: node.js, neural-network, brain.js

I decided to get known with a neural network in js. I took brain.js library as an example. This is taken from their GitHub page. I can understand what that we have two input neurons 1 and 0. do I get also two output 1and 0? I read about the weights, where are they here and i don't really understand what are they? In output what do we pass?

```
var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([{input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
           {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},
           {input: [1, 0], output: [1]},
           {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}]);

var output = net.run([1, 0]);  // [0.987
```

Comment: There is one output neuron. This neuron returns the predicted value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple neural network that approximates the XOR logic operator.
The result of the network will be in range from 0 to 1.

The result will (mathematically) approach 1 the larger the training set gets.
Because this is a simple example the value predicted is close enough.

Usually, one will use a threshold/stepping function like the sigmoid function, to transform the output from linearly separable to approximately binary.

**Here's a possible, simple NN for XOR approximation:**
[image]